# Javascript command for Google Chrome download location

Tags: javascript, file, location

I was wondering if there is a command or something that gives access to Chrome's downloads location. I mean this frame on Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From a webpage? Hell no. Lots of security and fingerprinting issues could arise from that very easily.

From an extension, doesn't look like it. Feel free to [check through the docs yourself](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index), but I didn't see it under any category I thought it might be under.

Comment: I checked the API and I don't think there is such thing. Basically what I want to do is to use it in an extension, something like a shortcut to the settings panel.

Comment: `chrome://settings` is as good as you're going to get. You can't do something like `chrome://settings#Downloads` unfortunately, why you can't I'm not sure.